# PHP split and replace

Tags: php, replace, split

I've got this code:

```
$username = $_GET['us'];
```

and:

```
$k1 = $_GET['set,vip'];
```

But it can be also:

```
$k1 = $_GET['set,vip;give,212'];
```

or

```
$k1 = $_GET['set,vip;give,212;op'];
```

and I want to check which one is it and get this:

```
$ko1 = 'set vip'
```

or:

```
$ko1 = 'set vip'
$ko2 = 'give 212'
```

or:

```
$ko1 = 'set vip'
$ko2 = 'give 212'
$ko3 = 'op'
```

to finaly make this:

```
$komenda1 = $ko3.' '.$username;
$komenda2 = $ko3.' '.$username;
$komenda3 = $ko3.' '.$username;
```

and this is my code:

```
<?PHP
$username = $_GET['us'];
        $k1 = $_GET['set,vip;give,212'];
        $k1i = $_GET['2'];
        $arr2 = explode(";", $k1, $k1i); //podziel na komendy 
            if ($kli='1'){
                $kk11 = arr2[0] //np set,vip
                $komenda11 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk11);
            }elseif ($kli='2'){
                $kk11 = arr2[0]; //np set,vip
                $komenda11 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk11);
                $kk12 = arr2[1]; //np set,vip
                $komenda12 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk12);
            }elseif ($kli='3'){
                $kk11 = arr2[0]; //np set,vip
                $komenda11 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk11);
                $kk12 = arr2[1]; //np set,vip
                $komenda12 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk12);
                $kk13 = arr2[2]; //np set,vip
                $komenda13 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk13);
            }
        $k2 = $_GET['k2']; //pierwsza część komendy np set,vip;give,212
        $k2i = $_GET['k2i']; //ilość komend
        $arr3 = explode(";", $k1, $k1i); //podziel na komendy 
            if ($kli='1'){
                $kk21 = arr3[0]; //np set,vip
                $komenda21 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk21);
                $komenda1 = $komenda11.$username.$komenda21;
                print($komenda1);

            }elseif ($kli='2'){
                $kk21 = arr3[0]; //np set,vip
                $komenda21 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk21);
                $kk22 = arr3[1]; //np set,vip
                $komenda22 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk22);
                $komenda1 = $komenda11.$username.$komenda21;
                $komenda2 = $komenda12.$username.$komenda22;
                print($komenda1);
                print($komenda2);
            }elseif ($kli='3'){
                $kk21 = arr3[0]; //np set,vip
                $komenda21 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk21);
                $kk22 = arr3[1]; //np set,vip
                $komenda22 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk22);
                $kk23 = arr3[2]; //np set,vip
                $komenda23 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk23);
                $komenda1 = $komenda11.$username.$komenda21;
                $komenda2 = $komenda12.$username.$komenda22;
                $komenda3 = $komenda13.$username.$komenda23;
                print($komenda1);
                print($komenda2);
                print($komenda3);
            }
?>
```

but it give me this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/example.pl/test.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `arr2` on several lines without a dollar sign, so PHP is not recognizing it as a variable. Change it to `$arr2`

Comment: Yes, thats it, but now i've got another problem: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/example.pl/test.php on line 8

Comment: That's `$komenda11 = $str_replace ( ',' , ' ' , $kk11);` and it has the same problem but reversed: the function is `str_replace`, not `$str_replace`.